# Magento 2 CSS .less files with @variables

Tags: magento2, css, less-css

I'm having trouble changing the max-width of a theme in Magento 2.

I've found the CSS in:

```
<THEME>/web/css/source/_layout.less

max-width: @layout__max-width;
```

Then in the Magento Lib folder there is documentation for the variable:

```
@layout__max-width              
Default: 1280px
Allowed Values: '' | false | value
Comment: Page maximum width
```

So i tried adding a new definition to my _layout.less file

```
@layout__max-width:1185px;
```

Also tried adding the same definition to _theme.less file

But i'm still getting max-width of 1280px

Any ideas what i've done wrong would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Clear cache and check again.

Comment: Can you please let me know the right way of modifying the less vraible, I have tried @TiEul answer but that is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you put the file in the wrong directory, the correct location is:

`app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/web/css/source/lib/variables/_layout.less`

I just tried your example locally and it worked fine when I put it in the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

You can write this code in `_theme.less`

```
@layout__max-width:1185px;
```

Comment: Hi, I've already put that code into the _theme.less file and its had no effect

Answer (score 0):

Directly copy and past _layout.less file from lib directory to theme directory is not best practice.

You can Extend your _layout.less file

In your theme directory, create a web/css/source/lib/variables/ sub-directory.

Add _layout_extend.less and _extend.less file to web/css/source dierectory.

In web/css/source/lib/variables/_layout_extend.less file add your code for the layout variable override. like @layout__max-width:1185px;
In web/css/source/_extend.less register the _layout_extend.less by adding the following code: @import 'lib/variables/_layout_extend.less';

With this you will extend the magento default styles not override.

For more information please see the Magento documentation.
thanks.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html